# Java Concurrency Time Performance: Executors, ThreadGroup or Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I'm starting to develop some multi-thread plataform to a project that allready exists (a non-multithreaded project) in Java and i need a performance GAIN, reducing the time of complex calculations that are all over the project.

I've being using Executors but i dont't really know if it's the best solution for performance gain compared to ThreadGroup or pure Runnable.

So, which one should be used?

Comment: There isn't an inherently faster or slower one. Executors and ThreadGroup provide simpler/easier-to-use interfaces than basic Thread classes. Runnable has nothing to do with it, since Runnable is an interface, not an implementation. Also, be aware that making something multithreaded does not magically make it run faster. In some cases, introducing concurrency can make things run _slower_ due to resource contention.

Comment: Most part of your gain, if there will be any, will be in identifying parts of your work which can be done in parallel. Other than that, there'll be no major difference performance-wise if you use pure Threads or executors.

Comment: You are better of trying to optimise your code. If you have 4 core, you might hope to improve your performance by 4x, but by optimising your code (using a profiler to guide you) you can improve the performance by 10 - 1000x. IMHO Its only worth using multiple threads when the code is as efficient as it can be already.

Comment: Thanks to all! Matt i did know that i have to watch out for not making a mess when using multithreads, and that i could end up with slower (for bad programming i guess) performance, like for example a thread that keeps getting the processor for use and does nothing more than a simple print. Victor, thanks for your answer, also helped me a lot!

Comment: Peter, I did one optimization with multithread allready and the gain (using executors) was up to %30 but i guess your right, maybe i just have to optimise my code first. What's a profiler ?? (guess i will google it, or stackoverflow it hehe) Thank you for your HO !!! help me a lot 2 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will only get a performance gain from thread pools if you reuse them for several computations (i.e. you start a pool with 10 threads and perform 10 tasks 100 times, instead of starting 10 threads every time 100 times). They still take an initial overhead to start up, you can't escape this part. So here's an example:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    exec.submit(new Task(i));
}    

// later

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    exec.submit(new Task(i));
}    

exec.shutdown(); // etc.
```

In this case, I only pay the overhead of starting 10 threads once, at the beginning.

Using pure threads:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Task(i));
    threads.add(t);       
    t.start();   
}  

for(Thread t: threads) {
    t.join();
}

// later I need more work

threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Task(i));
    threads.add(t);        
    t.start();  
}  

for(Thread t: threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

In this case I pay the overhead of starting 10 threads twice, which is a bad use of threading. Of course, if you only need to execute those tasks once, there won't be any performance difference, except that it's easier to work with executors.

I don't get what you mean by pure `Runnable` (pure threads maybe?), since thread pools (executors) also work on `Runnable`s.

Comment: Thanks Tudor! That clarified my head and is the answer that brighten my brain more than the shiniest tooth on earth! And what i mean by "pure Runnable" is that i did know that Executors work on Runnable's and i just tought that i would have a better distinction between both ways of handling threads!!

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadGroup` is a way of organizing threads and is rarely used.

`Executors` take "pure" `Runnable` so I assume you meant to compare `Executors` with forking your own threads?  Both of these solutions would be similar in terms of a performance GAIN but the `ExecutorService` classes are significantly easily to use.  They allow you to submit a series of `Runnable` classes that are executed in parallel depending on how many threads you give the pool.

The real trick is figuring out to divide your work into jobs that can execute in parallel -- either in a thread that you fork or via a thread-pool.

A common code pattern with `Executors`:

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// or you can create an open-ended thread pool
// ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// submit my jobs which are classes that implement Runnable
for (MyRunnable myRunnable : myRunnables) {
   threadPool.submit(myRunnable);
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks Gray! Can i tell that ThreadGroup is kind of @deprecated ? Also, i just tought that EXECUTORS use and RUNNABLE interface use could have some performance diference between then in java code.. but i guess i was completly wrong, as you said both are similar, as others said 2. Thanks for adding the common code pattern, ill help others! Regards,